# Preventing implicit conversion of some arguments in a templated member function

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, implicit, explicit

Currently I have a member function defined as such:

```
template<typename T> bool updateParameter(const std::string& name, const T& data);
```

With an overload for pointers.

```
template<typename T> bool updateParameter(const std::string& name, T* data);
```

I would like to be able to use this function as such:

```
int test = 20;
updateParameter<int>("name", 0);
updateParameter<int>("Referenced parameter", &test);
```

This way I can have a parameter object that either owns the data that it represents, or points to a user owned member.

Now the problem that I have is with the current setup MSVC implicitly will convert the const 0 of "name" to a pointer, so it ends up calling the overload designed for pointers.  I can use the explicit keyword, but then I can't get the implicit conversion from const char[] to std::string for the name parameter.
Is there a way of telling the compiler, MSVC and GCC that a certain field should not be implicitly converted, or at least for it to prefer the const T& version over the T* version?

Comment: I've tried to replicate your issue, but to me both GCC 4.8.4 and VS2010 behave correctly.

Comment: The `const T&` overload should definitely be preferred for `0`, even if you don't specify `<int>`. I can't reproduce on any compiler.

Comment: Work as expected [here](https://ideone.com/PnKPLV).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a VC++ bug. The first argument's conversion is identical for both overloads (`char const[5]` => `std::string const&`).
For the second argument, there are two distinct standard conversion sequences though: For the `T const&`-overload, the conversion is an identity conversion - §13.3.3.1.4/1:

> When a parameter of reference type binds directly (8.5.3) to an
>   argument expression, the implicit conversion sequence is the identity
>   conversion, unless the argument expression has a type that is a
>   derived class of the parameter type […]

However, converting `0` to a pointer type has Conversion rank. §4.10 goes

> A *null pointer constant* is an integer literal (2.13.2) with value zero
>   or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. A null pointer constant can be
>   converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null pointer value* of
>   that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object
>   pointer or function pointer type. Such a conversion
>   is called a *null pointer conversion*.

And §13.3.3.1.1/3 categorizes that accordingly, while also listing our identity conversion and how both relate:

[image]

---

The best workaround is to simply upgrade VC++, as recent versions select the correct overload (e.g. compare with [rextester's VC++](http://rextester.com/YAYE93057)).
Another option is to take `data` by reference instead for your second overload. Ambiguities would be prevented by §13.3.3.2/3.2.6. Or simply don't overload `updateParameter` at all and provide a second function template instead.